# In Java / Scala, how create a new Spark SQL Dataset by select row's index like Pandas?

Tags: java, sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I can't find any API in Spark SQL to select a Dataset by row's index similar to https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html

Eg: Pandas

```py
# Dataframe: df1
#            0         2         4         6
# 0   0.149748 -0.732339  0.687738  0.176444
# 2   0.403310 -0.154951  0.301624 -2.179861
# 4  -1.369849 -0.954208  1.462696 -1.743161
# 6  -0.826591 -0.345352  1.314232  0.690579
# 8   0.995761  2.396780  0.014871  3.357427
# 10 -0.317441 -1.236269  0.896171 -0.487602

df1.iloc[:3]
#           0         2         4         6
# 0  0.149748 -0.732339  0.687738  0.176444
# 2  0.403310 -0.154951  0.301624 -2.179861
# 4 -1.369849 -0.954208  1.462696 -1.743161

df1.iloc[1:5, 2:4]
#           4         6
# 2  0.301624 -2.179861
# 4  1.462696 -1.743161
# 6  1.314232  0.690579
# 8  0.014871  3.357427
```

The only solutions I can come up with is by adding an "id" column then do a where to select by rows ID.

Eg:

```java
// Create New Dataset with rows at 10
// Or rows from 10 -> 20
// Or multiple rows: 10, 12, 22,...
df = df.withColumn("id",functions.monotonically_increasing_id()) // Or row_number()
    .where("id BETWEEN 10 AND 20")
    .drop("id")
```

Is there any API in Spark that can do this OR is there a better way?

Comment: Can you clarify what the syntax does in Python? What does `df1` contains in your example?

Comment: I guess `offset` and `take` are what you're looking for though.

Comment: Function 'row_number' over Window can be used. But performance will be bad.

Comment: @GaëlJ I have added the Dataframe df1 elements to my example

Comment: @GaëlJ `offset` would also work. Do you know if there is any other aways to do it similar to pandas?